# Flash CS4 - can I increase FLV-video playing speed by AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

There is a cycled video in a background loaded in Movie Clip. Is it possible to increase flv-video playing speed(in a certain moment) by AS3?

Comment: Is it embeded as Video clip or video is external and loaded by code?

Comment: It's no matter-I'll do it by the better way.